# gson.fromJson StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, android, json, gson, stack-overflow

I don't know why it doesn't work, I think I'm doing it correctly.

### Error

```
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.imaginarv.launcher, PID: 11957
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:383)
10-29 09:22:48.995 11957-11957/com.imaginarv.launcher E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:378)
```

### apps.json

This file is stored on assets/apps.json.
I checked it on [http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

```
[
  {
    "name": "Carpeta 1",
    "packages": [
      "com.mobilendo.app1",
      "com.mobilendo.app2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Carpeta 2",
    "packages": [
      "com.mobilendo.app1",
      "com.mobilendo.app2"
    ]
  }
]
```

### Functions

Functions to read the JSon from apps.json and parse it.

```
private ArrayList<FolderModel> getFolders() {
    String jsonString = loadJSONFromAsset();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<FolderModel> foldersList;
    foldersList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<FolderModel>>(){}.getType());

    return foldersList;
}

public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream json = getAssets().open("apps.json");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buf.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

### FolderModel

```
public class FolderModel {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("packages")
    private ArrayList<String> packages;

    @SerializedName("apps")
    private ArrayList<AppModel> apps;

    @SerializedName("icon")
    private Drawable icon;

    public FolderModel(String name, ArrayList<String> packages) {
        this.name = name;
        this.packages = packages;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPackages() {
        return packages;
    }

    public void setPackages(ArrayList<String> packages) {
        this.packages = packages;
    }

    public ArrayList<AppModel> getApps() {
        return apps;
    }

    public void setApps(ArrayList<AppModel> apps) {
        this.apps = apps;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

### AppModel

```
public class AppModel implements Serializable {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ApplicationInfo mInfo;

    private String mAppLabel;
    private Drawable mIcon;

    private boolean mMounted;
    private final File mApkFile;

    public AppModel(Context context, ApplicationInfo info) {
        mContext = context;
        mInfo = info;

        mApkFile = new File(info.sourceDir);
    }

    public ApplicationInfo getAppInfo() {
        return mInfo;
    }

    public String getApplicationPackageName() {
        return getAppInfo().packageName;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return mAppLabel;
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        if (mIcon == null) {
            if (mApkFile.exists()) {
                mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
                return mIcon;
            } else {
                mMounted = false;
            }
        } else if (!mMounted) {
            // If the app wasn't mounted but is now mounted, reload
            // its icon.
            if (mApkFile.exists()) {
                mMounted = true;
                mIcon = mInfo.loadIcon(mContext.getPackageManager());
                return mIcon;
            }
        } else {
            return mIcon;
        }

        return mContext.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon);
    }


    public void loadLabel(Context context) {
        if (mAppLabel == null || !mMounted) {
            if (!mApkFile.exists()) {
                mMounted = false;
                mAppLabel = mInfo.packageName;
            } else {
                mMounted = true;
                CharSequence label = mInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
                mAppLabel = label != null ? label.toString() : mInfo.packageName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. Could you introduce what you are trying to achieve, and only paste relevant parts of code so that the questin can be useful to others. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you post AppModel and Drawable

Comment: Please post your AppModel class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Drawable object from FolderModel and from AppModel and save it as an id or image url.
The Drawables are not serializable clases and it's expensive to keep them in memory.

Comment: Don't work, only work without AppModel array list and Drawable.

Comment: Yes, I know, but GSON doesn't know if there is a drawable before searching for it. So, GSON breaks because it searches for some drawable. Just try it, if it isn't the problem we search for another solucion

Comment: I remove Drawable and don't work, only work if I remove Drawable and AppModel.

Comment: Yes! It's because in AppModel you have a Drawable too! Try to remove it too.

Comment: Works! Thank you @ezefire

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
JSONArray list;
list = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                foldersList = new ArrayList<FolderModel>();
                FolderModel f;
                for (int i = 1; i < list.length(); ++i) {
                    f=new FolderModel();
                    JSONObject obj = list.getJSONObject(i);

                    f.setName(obj.getString("name").toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use another way to parse:

```
 FolderModel[] arrayModels = gson.fromJson(jsonString, FolderModel[].class);
```